# Is it legal to use Overleaf templates?

Tags: templates, overleaf

I want to use the American Political Science Association 2021 template from Overleaf. But I do not want to publish to the American Political Science Association. I just need a good looking template for a university homework.

Comment: legal questions are not on topic here but most overleaf templates are published with open source licences, you need to check the one you use

Comment: Not a lawyer but I checked the license of that specific template and it is "Attribution 4.0 International (CC BY 4.0)", you can read more here but it should be okay: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/

Comment: But (without looking at his one at all) I would not take some large publisher template which is hard to configure and designed to enforce a publisher house style for  "university homwork". Just use a basic well known class such as `article` or `amsart`